# Can´t get handshake to wss://echo.websocket.org/ with UnitySocketIO

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket

I do basic sample integrating UnitySocketIO https://github.com/NetEase/UnitySocketIO/ with unity but I get an error, someone tried to do?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using SocketIOClient;
using WebSocket4Net;

public class WsConnection : MonoBehaviour {

    Client client;
    string url = "wss://echo.websocket.org";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        client = new Client(url, WebSocketVersion.DraftHybi00);
        client.Opened += SocketOpened;
        client.Message += SocketMessage;
        client.SocketConnectionClosed += SocketConnectionClosed;
        client.Error +=SocketError;

        client.Connect();

    }

    private void SocketOpened(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        //invoke when socket opened
        client.Send("hello world");
    }

    private void SocketMessage (object sender, MessageEventArgs e) {
        if ( e!= null && e.Message.Event == "message") {
            string msg = e.Message.MessageText;
            //process(msg);
            Debug.Log(msg);

            client.Close();
        }
    }

    private void SocketConnectionClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        //invoke when socket opened
        Debug.Log("Conexion cerrada...");
    }


    private void SocketError(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        //invoke when socket opened
        Debug.Log(((SocketIOClient.ErrorEventArgs)e).Message);
    }

}
```

ouput is:

> Error initializing handshake with wss://echo.websocket.org/

I've tried with ws and wss protocol

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
client = new Client(url, WebSocketVersion.Rfc6455);
```

RFC6455 is the final WebSocket standard specification.

Comment: I've tried all the standards that the library supports: WebSocketVersion.DraftHybi10, WebSocketVersion.DraftHybi00, WebSocketVersion.None, WebSocketVersion.Rfc6455...  but the error is the same